# Generating function signatures for rvalue/lvalue refs with metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I want to pass both rvalues and lvalues to my functions, but I don't want to write all O(2<sup>n</sup>) function signatures, where n is the number of arguments. For example, for my String append function:

```
inline static String append(String&& l1, String&& l2) {
    l1.append(l2);
    return l1;
}
inline static String append(String&& l1, String& l2) {
    l1.append(std::forward<String>(l2));
    return l1;
}
inline static String append(String& l1, String&& l2) {
    l1.append(l2);
    return l1;
}
inline static String append(String &l1, String& l2) {
    return append(std::forward<String>(l1), std::forward<String>(l2));
}
```

That's too many function signatures! TMP is a Turing complete language, there's gotta be a way to generate all 4 versions of the same thing in compile time, with correct usage of `std::forward` right? Bonus points for C++17 magic.

Comment: You are misusing `forward` here.

Comment: More specifically, in your case it acts as `std::move`. It's intended to be used with universal references...

Comment: Isn't std::forward either an std::move or a no-op? How am I misusing it?

Comment: It is. But since you don't use universal references, in your case it always moves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// this will be in C++20
template <typename T>
using remove_cvref_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template <typename L=String, typename R=String,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<L>, String> &&
        std::is_same_v<remove_cvref_t<R>, String>,
        int> = 0>
inline static String append(L&& l, R&& r) {
    l.append(std::forward<R>(r));
    return std::forward<L>(l);
}
```

The default template parameters are there to allow things like *braced-init-list*s. The different constraints are because `R` can be some kind of reference to `const String`, but `L` cannot be.

---

Depending on your intended use, this may not be entirely right, as it prevents passing in types *derived* from `String` - whereas the original overloads do not. If you don't care about that, then this is fine. If you do, then you want to check `is_base_of` instead:

```
std::is_base_of_v<String, remove_cvref_t<L>> &&
std::is_base_of_v<String, remove_cvref_t<R>> &&
!std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<L>>
```

---

Alternatively to that, you could just constrain on `append` itself being well-formed:

```
template <typename L=String, typename R=String,
    typename = decltype(std::declval<L&>().append(std::declval<R>())),
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<L, String>, int> = 0>
inline static String append(L&& l, R&& r) { ... }
```

Comment: Inheritance is not an issue, in fact like I said in the comments, I want strict types on String, String& and String&&. I really really like your last trick, of speculatively calling append in compile time!

Comment: All in all though, its a real bummer that you have to chose between perfect forwarding and functional polymorphism. I hope C++20 addresses this in a more natural way.

Comment: @rausted I'm not sure what you mean by "functional polymorphism", or what is a bummer here?

Comment: If you have an `append(String a, String b)` and an `append(List<int> a, List<int> b)` function polymorphism allows the right one to be found based on the type signature and arguments. As of now, that's not possible with universal references since `T&&` is a Generic and we have to use TMP hacks to do this, like the one in your answer. I'd rather use polymorphism than SFINAE.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with

```
template<class T, class S> static inline auto append(T&& l1, S&& l2) {
    l1.append(std::forward<S>(l2));

    return std::forward<T>(l1);
}
```

Note that error messages will not exactly be easy to grasp, when the instantiation fails. This can be mitigated by properly constraining the template.

Comment: Hm I remember seeing that T&& is especially magic, so then it's not possible to specialize my arguments to Strings and get perfect forwarding?

Comment: You really should constrain the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-deduce the reference type:

```
template<typename Str>
std::remove_reference_t<Str> append(Str &&, Str &&);
```

If you want it to be exactly `String`, well

```
template<typename Str>
std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<Str>, String>
        , String>
append(Str &&, Str &&);
```

At least it's not quadratic. Few typedefs will compactify the whole thing.

Comment: this isn't generic enought, it wouldn't be able to take `const String&` and `String`